# Can I use question marks in SQLite table column name?

Tags: sql, sqlite

When I try to create a table with the following as a column name: "Admin?" in my SQLite Database, I get a SQL error saying:

`SQL error or missing database (near "?": syntax error)`

Here is my SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE test (admin? TEXT PRIMARY KEY);
```

I am assuming I cannot have question marks inside column names, but I cannot find any documentation about it. If this is the issue, is there any workaround here, or a better solution? Also, I am creating the table from Kotlin code, so I am not sure if that has any effect on it.

Comment: While you can do this by escaping the name, you're going to hate yourself later for doing so (you also have to escape it every time you want to use it). Better to use a better name like `IsAdmin` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the column name:

```
CREATE TABLE test ("admin?" TEXT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Comment: worked like a charm, so do the quotes escape all characters?

Comment: Better to use `"double quotes"` so it works also in `SELECT`s and other SQL where the context for literal/identifier is ambiguous.

Comment: @Alec: Basically yes. You could even use `"` when you double them. Although that might get really ugly really fast.